# After adding ssl certificate spring boot application fails to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

After i added ssl certificate by the instruction on this site https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/ application fails to start with following error:

```
***************************                                                                               
APPLICATION FAILED TO START                                                                               
***************************                                                                               

Description:                                                                                              

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or th
e connector may be misconfigured.
```

When i change the port i get the same error. `netstat -ntulp` shows there is no programms are running on that port. When i comment lines associated with ssl in application.properties the server starts normally. Please help me

Comment: Are you running it as root?

Comment: You can try to start Spring boot with a different port using command --server.port=8081

Comment: @JosephSible i running it as root.

Comment: @Sambit i already mentioned that i tried to start app on different port

Comment: I am having the similar issue followed the same link, please share your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your backend just like that:

1. Add dependency:

   ```
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
   ```
2. Provide RestTemplate bean:

```java
@Bean
private RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SSLContext sslContext = buildSslContext();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

private SSLContext buildSslContext() {
        try {
            char[] keyStorePassword = sslProperties.getKeyStorePassword();
            return new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(
                            KeyStore.getInstance(new File(sslProperties.getKeyStore()), keyStorePassword),
                            keyStorePassword
                    ).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to instantiate SSL context", ex);
        } finally {
            sslProperties.setKeyStorePassword(null);
            sslProperties.setTrustStorePassword(null);
        }
    }
```

3. Provide required SSL properties in your application.properties or application.yaml file:

```
server:
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: /path/to/key.keystore
        key-store-password: password
        key-alias: alias
        trust-store: /path/to/truststore
        trust-store-password: password
```

That's it. Now you can see your Tomcat is starting on 8080 (or another port) (https).

Alternatively, you can use [my spring boot starter](https://github.com/EugeneLesnov/spring-boot-starter-rest)